# Killing forked process in a socket server

Tags: c, sockets, fork, defunct

I've written a socket based multi client server and a client as an assigment, but I don't seem to be able to get rid of forked processes. Every time I close the client, or enter the exiting command, the process doesn't seem to close. When checked `ps aux| grep server` there is a defuct process. How can I get rid of them, what am I doing wrong when closing forked prosses.

The server:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <strings.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <time.h>

void error(char *msg)
{
    perror(msg);
    exit(1);
}

void doprocessing (int sock)
{
   int n;
   char buffer[5];
   time_t rawtime;
   char tim[22];
   char dat[20];
   char day[16];
   char yer[18];

   while(1)
   {
     bzero(buffer,5);
     n = read(sock,buffer,5);

     if (n < 0) error("ERROR reading from socket");

     printf("Got %.3s command.\n",buffer);

     if (strcasecmp(buffer, "tim\n") == 0)
     {
        rawtime = time(NULL);
        strncpy(tim, "Current time: ", 14);
        strncpy(tim+14, (ctime(&rawtime))+11, 8);
        n = write(sock, tim, 22);
     }
     else if (strcasecmp(buffer, "dat\n") == 0)
     {
        rawtime = time(NULL);
        strncpy(dat, "Current date: ", 14);
        strncpy(dat+14, (ctime(&rawtime))+4, 6);
        n = write(sock, dat, 20);
     }
     else if (strcasecmp(buffer, "day\n") == 0)
     {
        rawtime = time(NULL);
        strncpy(day, "Current day: ", 13);
        strncpy(day+13, (ctime(&rawtime)), 3);
        n = write(sock, day, 16);
     }
     else if (strcasecmp(buffer, "yer\n") == 0)
     {
        rawtime = time(NULL);
        strncpy(yer, "Current year: ", 14);
        strncpy(yer+14, (ctime(&rawtime))+20, 4);
        n = write(sock, yer, 18);
     }
     else if (strcasecmp(buffer, "com\n") == 0)
     {
        n = write(sock, "TIM - current time\nDAT - Month and day\nDAY - current weekday\nYER - Year\nEXT - exit", 82);
     }
     else if (strcasecmp(buffer, "ext\n") == 0)
     {
        n = write(sock, "Exiting", 7);
        break;
     }
     else  n = write(sock, "Wrong command enter COM to see commands.",40);

     if (n < 0) error("ERROR writing to socket");}
   }

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int sockfd, newsockfd, portno, clilen, n;
    char buffer[256];
    struct sockaddr_in serv_addr, cli_addr;
    int pid;

    if (argc < 2)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "ERROR, no port provided");
        exit(1);
    }

    sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);

    if (sockfd < 0) error("ERROR opening socket");

    bzero((char *) &serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr));
    portno = atoi(argv[1]);

    serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    serv_addr.sin_port = htons(portno);
    serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;

    if (bind(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *) &serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr)) < 0) error("ERROR on binding");

    listen(sockfd, 5);
    clilen = sizeof(cli_addr);

    while(1)
    {
         newsockfd = accept(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *) &cli_addr, &clilen);
         if (newsockfd < 0) error("ERROR on accept");


         pid = fork();

         if (pid < 0) error("ERROR on fork");

         if (pid == 0)
         {
             close(sockfd);
             doprocessing(newsockfd);
             exit(-1);
         }
         else close(newsockfd);
    }
    close(sockfd);
    return 0;
}
```

The Client:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <netdb.h> 

void error(const char *msg)
{
    perror(msg);
    exit(0);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int sockfd, portno, n;
    struct sockaddr_in serv_addr;
    struct hostent *server;

    char rbuffer[256];
    char sbuffer[256];

    if (argc < 3)
    {
       fprintf(stderr,"usage %s hostname port\n", argv[0]);
       exit(0);
    }

    portno = atoi(argv[2]);
    sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);

    if (sockfd < 0) error("ERROR opening socket");

    server = gethostbyname(argv[1]);

    if (server == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr,"ERROR, no such host\n");
        exit(0);
    }

    bzero((char *) &serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr));
    serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    bcopy((char *)server->h_addr, (char *)&serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr, server->h_length);
    serv_addr.sin_port = htons(portno);

    if (connect(sockfd,(struct sockaddr *) &serv_addr,sizeof(serv_addr)) < 0) error("ERROR connecting");

    while(1)
    {
       printf("Enter a command: ");
       bzero(sbuffer,sizeof(sbuffer));
       fgets(sbuffer,255,stdin);
       n = write(sockfd,sbuffer,5);
       if (n < 0) error("ERROR writing to socket");

       bzero(rbuffer,sizeof(rbuffer));
       n = read(sockfd,rbuffer,255);
       if (n < 0) error("ERROR reading from socket");

       printf("%s\n",rbuffer);

       if (strcasecmp(sbuffer, "ext\n") == 0) break;
    }
    close(sockfd);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A process is going to be visible in ps output as 'defunct' (sometimes called **zombie** process) until it's exit status is going to be collected with `wait()` or `waitpid()`.

There are following ways of getting rid of those zombie processes:

1. Wait for child completion using `wait()` or `waitpid()` in parent process. Obviously, it's hard to do anything else in the parent this way.
2. Create a separate thread immediately after spawning a child and `waitpid` inside this thread.
3. In your parent, install a handler for SIGCHLD signal and `waitpid()` inside this handler.
4. If your system allows that, set to ignore SIGCHLD signal.